# Mensagem "Could not reserve enough space for object heap" no JVM

Tags: java, memória, heap, jvm

Então queria saber qual a limitação para alocação de memória para a JVM dependendo do sistema operacional e arquitetura do processador. Se conforme configurar, diminuir o valor máximo do perm-size para um valor inferior, é possível aumentar ainda mais o Java *heap* size?

Exemplo:

No Windows 32bits

Havia configurado o Java `MaxPermSize` com 512m, isso me permitia deixar até ~1024m de *heap* size

Depois alterei o Java `MaxPermSize` para 256m, eu consegui por o *heap* size até ~1200m.

Já no windows 64 com Java Jdk 64bits não tinha esse problema, apenas se utiliza-se java JDK 32bits.

Se alguém souber de uma documentação, por favor também enviar um link.

Answer (score 4):

Como o limite dos sistemas 32bits é 4GB de RAM e o sistema precisa de memória para Swap, kernel entre outros o limite prático está em torno de 1,4GB  a 1,6 GB [(fonte)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit).

Relação entre *PermSize* e *HeapSize*:

> heap tradicional = **objetos**
>
> perm heap = **definições de classes**

Ou seja o perm heap é um espaço adicional e separado do espaço da heap convencional (para objetos). Logo quanto maior o espaço que definir para isso mais espaço ocupará do sistema e isso limitará o máximo que o seu sistema irá permitir para o heap convencional.

Portanto o Perm heap não está incluso no heap (Xmx) mas ele poderá limitá-lo por consumir um espaço adicional do sistema que num sistema 32bits será bem mais limitado que em um 64bits.

Exemplificando: `512Mb + 1024Mb = 1.5Gb` (espaço total que o seu sistema permitiu para a JVM) que como pode ver está na faixa descrita no começo dessa resposta.

Veja a documentação oficial no site da [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10391_01/doc.910/e10361/tuningforappserver.htm).

**A tabela abaixo mostra como definir essas opções na JVM**

```
+-----------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Opção da JVM    | Significado                            | Exemplo             |
| -Xms            | heap size inicial da JVM               | -Xms3072M           |
| -Xmx            | tamanho máximo do heap da JVM          | -Xmx16G             |
| -XX:PermSize    | tamanho inicial do espaço permanente   | -XX:PermSize=128k   |
| -XX:MaxPermSize | tamannho máximo do espaço permanente   | -XX:MaxPermSize=256m|
+-----------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

<sub>Acredito que seja útil ter essa tabela em uma resposta sobre issojá que suspeito que nem todos sabem como configurar tais elementos</sub>