# Heap de memória Java

Tags: java, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória, jvm, heap

Gostaria de uma explicação de forma simples o que é o *heap* de memória da JVM? Eu pesquisei no Google porém não tinha nenhuma resposta clara o suficiente.

Comment: Não é específico para o Java, mas já vai ajudar. As diferenças não são grandes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%c3%a3o-e-onde-est%c3%a3o-o-stack-e-heap e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101

Comment: mas no caso do java isso seria o lugar onde fica de fato guardado os objetos?

Comment: Os objetos criados à partir de classes, sim. Os objetos primitivos não, estes ficam no *stack*. Mais links http://www.infoq.com/br/articles/intro-memoria-JVM e http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/j-codetoheap/

Comment: Eu já expliquei sobre o Heap e o Perm Heap [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30221/mensagem-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap-no-jvm).

Comment: @user16049 Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 17):

Primeiro entenda que estamos falando de um conceito abstrato. É um nome só para facilitar nosso entendimento. Não existe um componente de *hardware* chamado *heap* localizado na memória. Nem mesmo uma área específica da memória onde "fica" o *heap*. Ele está espalhado por toda a memória.

## Heap

De forma simples o *heap* é a área da memória em que os objetos da sua aplicação são armazenados. Mas não é qualquer tipo de objeto que é guardado lá, apenas aqueles criados à partir de classes, ou seja, os objetos com semântica de referência.

Nele são alocados objetos que são referenciados em algum lugar, por isso são chamados objetos por referência. Java, hoje, incentiva muito que a maioria das alocações ocorram desta forma.

É uma área de memória gerenciada pelo *garbage colector*. Ela vai ocupando espaços conforme a necessidade e o GC, em algum momento futuro, vai liberando os espaços quando os dados contidos em uma determinada porção não são mais necessários. A liberação não é feita logo após o objeto não ser mais necessário.

Esta área não precisa ser contínua, ela é apenas uma *porção*, um *monte* da memória alocada para sua aplicação. E estamos falando da memória virtual que pode ser RAM, disco ou outra forma que o sistema operacional disponibilize.

A forma como ele é usado é sob demanda, ou seja, vai alocando espaços específicos conforme a necessidade. No caso da JVM boa parte desta alocação já é reservada com antecedência pelo GC. Ele tenta administrar a memória da melhor forma possível. Mas você precisa enxergar este tipo de alocação como sob demanda, que ela vai sendo usada conforme a necessidade.

## Stack

Objetos curtos e de curta duração que são armazenados diretamente com seu valor ficam na *stack* (alguma otimização pode fazer isso com tipo por referência). Este é o caso dos objetos de tipos primitivos e será quando a linguagem tiver outros tipos que não são nem primitivos e nem criados com classes. Algumas pessoas esquecem que os dados primitivos também são objetos (e nem é porque Java é orientada a objeto, na verdade é um outro conceito de objeto). Talvez até porque Java não costume usar o termo objeto para estes dados. Mas eles são objetos. Em C que não é nada orientada a objeto você os chama de objetos.

O funcionamento desta área é semelhante a uma *pilha*, daí o nome. É uma área de tamanho fixo de memória, normalmente contínua em que os dados vão sendo empilhados conforme eles precisam ser alocados e desempilhados quando não mais são necessários. E a ordem de desempilhamento deve ser obrigatoriamente inversa ao empilhamento. Isto torna esta área muito rápida. Mas sua limitação é que tem um espaço que não pode crescer e que não pode destruir dados de forma aleatória. Você não pode, por exemplo, deixar um dado alocado recentemente ainda em uso e destruir outros não necessários que foram alocados antes.

## Mais detalhadamente

Para entender melhor sobre *stack* e *heap* veja [minha resposta genérica sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). A explicação não é tão simples mas não é tão complexa quanto o assunto realmente é. Também esclareço sobre a diferença entre tipos por valor e por referência [nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101) sobre o C#. A maior diferença é que o Java não permite criar tipos por valor, pelo menos até o Java 12 (está previsto no Java 13 ou depois), só os tipos primitivos são por valor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 12):

Todo mundo sabe que computadores são máquinas que trabalham com código binário. Tudo com que um computador lida são zeros e uns.

Então, quando você tem um dado no seu programa, você tem um conjunto de zeros e uns. Mas esse conjunto não pode simplesmente ficar solto no espaço - ele tem que estar bem localizado na memória RAM. Caso contrário, seu programa não saberia distinguir a folha de pagamento que você implementou de fotos de gatinhos carregadas numa aba aberta do seu navegador.

Em geral, *runtimes* como o do C++, e das plataformas Java e .NET, separam dois espaços na memória RAM (literalmente algo do tipo "do byte de número X até o byte de número Y") para cada programa que estiverem rodando. Esses dois espaços são geralmente chamados de *Stack* e *Heap*, mas esses nomes são arbitrários e convenções humanas, não de máquina.

Todos os objetos que você instancia em seu programa é **alocado e endereçado** na memória, em um desses dois espaços. Se ele vai para o *Stack* ou para o *Heap* depende de como o objeto é criado.

Objetos ditos **por valor** (em geral, os primitivos como `int`, `bool`, `double` etc.), bem como as **referências** declaradas dentro de um método, são alocados no Stack. Objetos **por referência** vão pro Heap.

E qual a diferença? *Stack* significa pilha. O *Stack* é feito de células, ou contextos... Toda vez que você chama um método, uma nova célula ou contexto é empilhada no stack, com as informações daquele método. Essa célula ou contexto existe enquanto o método não chegar ao seu fim, e todas as variáveis que o método precisa são alocadas nessa célula. Então, se temos algo como:

```
public void Foo() {
    int a = 0;
    boolean b = false;
    Bar();
}

public void Bar() {
    int b = 1;
    Ni();
}

public void Ni() {
    int c = 2;
}
```

Teremos um stack assim que cresce assim:

```
Foo -> |a == 0, b == false|
```

---

```
Bar -> |b == 1|
Foo -> |a == 0, b == false|
```

---

```
Ni  -> |c == 2|
Bar -> |b == 1|
Foo -> |a == 0, b == false|
```

Note que há dois objetos chamados `b`, com tipos e valores diferentes. Não tem problema. O programa "enxerga" apenas o contexto ou célula atual, que é a que estiver no topo a cada momento.

O Garbage Collector não tem poder nenhum aqui. Ele nunca vai desalocar e devorar os objetos na stack. No entanto, quando um método acaba, sua célula no *Stack* é desempilhada e destruída<strike>, levando todos os objetos alocados dentro daquela célula pro inferno dos objetos</strike>, o que acaba desalocando tudo que estiver lá.

Já no *Heap* não existe pilha. *Heap* significa montinho, e lá os objetos são alocados na base do "vai do jeito que encaixar". Os objetos sobrevivem entre chamadas de métodos, e ficam a mercê do Garbage Collector. Eles morrem quando o GC achar que eles devem morrer (o <strike>algoritmo de juízo final</strike> mecanismo do GC, no entanto, é tópico para outra pergunta).

Quando você instancia algo de uma classe, tipo:

```
ArrayList l1 = new ArrayList();
```

Você tem na verdade dois objetos. `l1` é uma referência ou ponteiro, e vai viver no *Stack*. Sua única função é informar ao programa em que endereço no *Heap* se encontra a lista que você criou com o comando `new List()`. Essa lista sobreviverá ao fim do escopo onde foi declarada.

Por isso, é mais rápido alocar e desalocar objetos no stack, mas eles só vão existir dentro do escopo de um método. Já no *Heap* existe gerenciamento de memória. É mais lento alocar e desalocar, mas os objetos sobrevivem ao método e morrem apenas quando não são mais necessários.

P.S.: um motivo pelo qual é bom ter objetos no *Heap* é que você não precisa copiar eles inteiros de uma chamada de método para outra. Se você tiver uma lista de um mega, coisas como:

```
Foo(l1); // aproveitando a que criamos mais acima
```

Você está trabalhando com um objeto que ocupa um mega na memória. Se lista fosse **por valor** ao invés de ser **por referência**, uma nova cópia da lista seria gerada toda vez que ela fosse passada como parâmetro, então só aqui seria o dobro de memória consumida. No final das contas, trabalhar com referências economiza memória na maioria dos casos.

Comment: @Maniero valeu! Faz tanto tempo que eu não toco em Java que eu já tinha esquecido XD

Comment: Não sei se isso é óbvio pra todo mundo ou não, mas não custa frisar: "Objetos ditos por valor (...), bem como as referências declaradas dentro de um método, são alocados no Stack..." *...quando* os mesmos são declarados em um método. Se uma classe possui um campo (atributo) esse campo faz parte dos dados dos seus objetos - e portanto ocupam espaço no *heap* (ainda que sejam tipos primitivos ou referências a outros objetos).