# Qual é a diferença entre On heap e Off Heap em Java - Memória da JVM

Tags: java, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória, jvm

Gostaria de uma explicação determinando as caraterísticas de **On heap** e **Off heap Memory** em Java.

Sabemos que `Thread Stacks`, o código da nossa aplicação e os `Buffers NIO` são todos alocados *Off heap*. Mas afinal, o que significa este termo?

Quais são as semanticas de alocacão de memória *On Heap* vs *Off Heap*?

Comment: Relacionado: ["Heap de memória Java"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36741/215) (obs.: *não é* duplicata - lá se fala da *heap* em termos mais gerais, aqui se trata de algo mais específico)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Gostaria de uma explicação determinando as caraterísticas de On heap e Off heap Memory em Java.*

**On-Heap Java Memory** é a memória gerenciada pela [Java Virtual Machine (JVM)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/), o *java heap* é estabelecido na inicialização do processo da *virtual machine*, e o seu tamanho pode ser especificado nesse momento:

```
java -Xmx2048m -Xms256m (... meus argumentos jvm ...)
```

Portanto *java heap* é um espaço em memória disponibilizado à instância da JVM para que esse seja utilizado durante a execução do programa ([*bytecode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode)), o *heap* em questão é compartilhado com todas *threads* pertencentes à instância da JVM ([processo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))).

#### Mas o que efetivamente "*fica*" no *Java Heap*?

**Todas as instâncias de classes criadas pela aplicação.**

Sendo direto, então temos o *Java Heap* como um ponto de armazenamento para todas alocações de memória efetuadas pela instância da JVM durante sua execução.

Quais as características mais marcantes desse *"ponto de armazenamento"*?

- Gerenciamento automático: *"a limpeza"* de memoria. (ou [Garbage Collection](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html))
- Não há necessidade de alocação de [memória contínua](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/3769/contiguous-memory-allocation) para os elementos (objetos) dentro do Heap.
- Alocação (ocupação efetiva) de espaço pelo Heap ocorre dinamicamente (para maior ou menor), respeitando os limites especificados na inicialização da JVM e do endereçamento do SO/Arquitetura.

---

> *Sabemos que Thread Stacks, o código da nossa aplicação e os Buffers NIO são todos alocados Off heap. Mas afinal, o que significa este termo?*

Para entender mais profundamente o conceito de *"On Heap"* e *"Off Heap"*, vamos visualizar o contexto de execução da instância da JVM:

[image: JVM Arquitetura]

Como você observou, uma **Thread Stack** (ou melhor *Java Virtual Machine Stack*) estaria "Off Heap" pelo fato de sua área de execução estar dentro de uma **Java Thread** e não ocorrer dentro do *Heap*.

[image: Thread Runtime Inside]

Agora quanto aos [Buffers NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/nio/index.html), o assunto começa a se estreitar. Claramente não existe uma *"runtime data area"* específica (na arquitetura JVM) para que seja feita alocação de memória fora do *jvm heap* nativamente.

Digamos que eu queira fazer um caching de um extenso conjunto (*Set*) de informações, normalmente manteríamos uma instancia estática no heap, e todas as [Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) poderiam referenciá-lo **"On heap"**.

#### E sobre "new I/O APIs" ou ByteBuffer e o "Off Heap"?

A [New I/O APIs](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=51) entrega de um recurso potencial a uma implementação **"Off Heap"** [Memory Mapped File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), esse é o [direct buffers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

Os pontos chave dele são:

- O conteúdo de um direct buffer *pode residir* em memória nativa, ou seja, fora do *heap* gerenciado pela JVM.
- Cada JVM [deve implementar nativamente](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/jni-14.html#NewDirectByteBuffer) as novas operações:

  - `NewDirectByteBuffer`
  - `GetDirectBufferAddress`
  - `GetDirectBufferCapacity`
- As operações de direct buffers são definidas por um [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

### Porque não "On Heap"?

Caso uma aplicação requeresse um volumoso conjunto de informações ao ponto que não seja  prático ou viável o seu gerenciamento no *heap*, pelo excesso de pausas causados pelo [Garbage Colletor](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) (ou por estratégias de GC conflitantes em áreas distintas do Heap) podendo nos deixar em face a problemas de [*java heap memory leak*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312069/the-best-memory-leak-definition).

Outro ponto seria a respeito de possíveis problemas a um não previsível (ou incompatível) volume de endereçamento de memória (lembre-se, para alocação de objetos no *heap* não é contínuo, mas para a JVM sim, o alcance/tamanho do *heap* deve ser especificado na criação do processo da JVM).

Assim como caso quiséssemos compartilhar esse mesmo *heap* entre instâncias de diferentes JVMs.

Nesses casos estratégia seria a alocação de memória **"Off Heap"**.

A característica definitiva da alocação **"Off Heap"** é que ela não compartilha do Heap de [arquitetura nativa da JVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html) e de todas suas características e gerenciamento por ela (Garbage Collection por exemplo).

> `Quais são as semânticas de alocacão de memória On Heap vs Off Heap?`

- Semântica de alocação **On Heap**:

  ```
  public class OffHeap {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          // TestObject é criado no jvm heap usando o operador new
          // t variavel local no stack recebe referencia de TestObject
          TestObject t = new TestObject();
      }
  }
  ```
- semântica de alocação **Off Heap**:

  Vou usar um exemplo de [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey) no Stack Overflow [Java - Swapping Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317664/java-swapping-page). Nesse código é criado um `HashMap` customizado suportando ser paginado em arquivos de memória "Off Heap".

  ```
  class LongIntParallelHashMultimap {
      private static final int NULL = 0;
      private final FileChannel channel1, channel2;
      private final LongBuffer keys;
      private final IntBuffer values;
      private final int capacity;
      private int size;

      public LongIntParallelHashMultimap(int capacity, String basename) throws IOException {
          assert (capacity & (capacity - 1)) == 0 : "Capacity " + capacity + " must be a power of 2";
          this.capacity = capacity;
          channel1 = new RandomAccessFile(basename + ".keys", "rw").getChannel();
          keys = channel1.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, capacity * 8).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asLongBuffer();
          // load keys into memory
          for(int i=0;i<capacity;i+=512) keys.get(i);

          channel2 = new RandomAccessFile(basename + ".values", "rw").getChannel();
          values = channel2.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, capacity * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
          for(int i=0;i<capacity;i+=1024) values.get(i);
      }

      public void put(long key, int value) {
          long key1 = key + 1;
          int index = indexFor(key1);
          while (keys.get(index) != NULL) {
              index = successor(index);
          }
          values.put(index, value);
          keys.put(index, key1);
          ++size;
      }

      /**
       * Uses a pre-allocated array and return the count of matches.
       */
      public int get(long key, int[] hits) {
          long key1 = key + 1;
          int index = indexFor(key1);
          int hitIndex = 0;

          while (keys.get(index) != NULL) {
              if (keys.get(index) == key1) {
                  hits[hitIndex] = values.get(index);
                  ++hitIndex;
              }
              index = successor(index);
          }

          return hitIndex;
      }

      private int indexFor(long key) {
          return Math.abs((int) ((key * 5700357409661598721L) & (capacity - 1)));
      }

      private int successor(int index) {
          return (index + 1) & (capacity - 1);
      }

      public int size() {
          return size;
      }

      public void close() {
          try {
              channel1.close();
              channel2.close();
          } catch (IOException ignored) {
          }
          try {
              ((DirectBuffer) keys).cleaner().clean();
              ((DirectBuffer) values).cleaner().clean();
          } catch (Throwable notSupportedOnThisPlatform) {
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  **Contexto de execução:**

  ```
  long heap = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
  RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("array.dat", "rw");
  IntBuffer map = raf.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 1 << 30).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
  for (int i = 0; i < map.capacity(); i++)
      map.put(i, i);
  long heap2 = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
  System.out.printf("Wrote %,d int values, heap used %,d bytes approx%n", map.capacity(), heap2 - heap);
  ```

  **Resultado:**

  ```
  Wrote 268,435,456 int values, heap used 0 approx
  ```

Answer (score 1):

## Off Heap vs On Heap

*On heap memory* é o espaço de memória controlado pela JVM (exemplo: limpeza de variáveis automática - GC) enquanto o *off heap memory* é controlado pelo desenvolvedor e é este quem precisa liberar (limpar) os espaços de memórias consumidos.

Algo que pode ajudar no entendimento do porque usar memória *off-heap*:

> A coleta de lixo (GC) em uma JVM pode ser um impedimento de
> desempenho. Um servidor não pode exercer controle sobre quando ocorre
> a coleta de lixo na memória heap da JVM e o servidor tem pouco
> controle sobre os acionadores para chamada.
>
> A memória fora do heap transfere valores para uma área de
> armazenamento que não está sujeita ao Java GC. Aproveitando o
> armazenamento fora de heap, um aplicativo pode reduzir a quantidade de
> armazenamento de heap que está sujeita à sobrecarga do GC.
>
> A memória fora do heap funciona em conjunto com o heap, não o
> substitui. As chaves são armazenadas no espaço de memória heap.
>
> **O armazenamento fora do heap é mais adequado para padrões de dados em que:**
>
> - Os valores armazenados são relativamente uniformes em tamanho
> - Os valores armazenados têm, em sua maioria, menos de 128 K de tamanho
> - Os padrões de uso envolvem ciclos de muitas criações seguidos por destruições ou limpezas
> - Os valores não precisam ser desserializados com frequência
> - Muitos dos valores são dados de referência de longa duração

Fonte:

[https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/managing/heap_use/off_heap_management.html#:~:text=Off%2Dheap%20memory%20offloads%20values,it%20does%20not%20replace%20it](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/managing/heap_use/off_heap_management.html#:%7E:text=Off%2Dheap%20memory%20offloads%20values,it%20does%20not%20replace%20it).

Answer (score -2):

A JVM possui um heap / free store de [tamanho definido](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/JVMTuning.html#1131866), e este tamanho pode ser [alterado](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/JVMTuning.html#1109778). Em C++, para alocar memória no heap, utiliza-se do operador *new* (Se não utilizar o operador new, a memória é alocada no stack de tamanho definido no momento de execução do programa). Em Java, toda alocação de memória é feita no heap by default (Nâo é possível alocar no stack), e o GC / Garbage Collector fica responsável pela "limpeza" e verificação da mesma (Por isso Java manteu a convenção de utilizar o operador new, mesmo sendo desnecessário / inútil no Java).

A diferença é aqui, é que ao utilizar C/C++, a alocação é feita no heap do OS, e no Java, a alocação é feita no heap da JVM. Quando esse tamanho limite é excedido em uma aplicação muito grande, é possível alocar memória no heap do OS por meio de serialização, e por isso chama-se ***off-heap***.

On-heap: Heap da JVM.
Off-heap: Heap do OS.

Comment: Não sei por que negativaram. Para mim, que não sou especialista em Java nem C++, a resposta parece OK. Porém as pessoas têm a liberdade de negativar sem comentar, tanto aqui como no site em inglês. Claro que incentivamos que comentem, para que o autor possa corrigir eventuais erros na resposta.

Comment: Discordo da sua resposta, o operador new é a instrução especifica para criação da instancia no JVM Heap, caso você não queria criar uma Struct-like no Heap é plenamente possível manipular toda a estrutura localmente no JVM Thread Stack.

Comment: Não votei negativo na sua resposta e só a estou vendo agora. O operador new não é desnecessário ou inútil no Java de forma nenhuma, o seu uso não se restringe só a questões de gerenciamento de memória, aliás este ponto chega a ser irrelevante em questão do uso do operador. No segundo parágrafo, você dá a entender que o que faz a memória ficar off-heap é o tamanho da aplicação, o que não é verdade. Enfim, me parece que a sua resposta está simplesmente errada, e por isso você recebeu os votos contrários.

Comment: [Não quis dizer que o operador new não cria uma instância, quis dizer que é inútil em termos de Language Design. O operador era completamente desnecessário, e mantiveram por mera convenção](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12445993/1795924).

E por "aplicação grande", fica implícita a ideia de grande alocação de memória no heap da JVM. [A diferença entre os dois termos é exatamente essa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6091680/1795924).